# Graph attributes in R

Tags: r, igraph, ggraph

I have no experience using R so apologies if this is a stupid question but I am on a tight deadline and have not been able to understand a clear answer from my own research.

I've just created a network graph and have changed some of the attributes, but others I can't get working:

1. How do I combine multiple arrows leading into one node into one higher-weighted arrow?
2. Why are the edges not changing to black, or any other colour that I try?
3. Is there a way for me to space out the nodes more so that they aren't all on top of each other around the centre, while 80% of the graph space isn't being used?

I've attached my code below, if you could implement the changes into the code exactly as I should write it to work then that would be very much appreciated.

```
library("igraph")
library("networkD3")
library("tidyverse")
library("igraph")
library("ggraph")


my_data <- read.csv("email-Eu-core-temporal-Dept3-CSV2.csv", header=TRUE)
my_network_frame <- data.frame(my_data$source_node, my_data$target_node)
my_network <- graph.data.frame(my_network_frame, directed=TRUE)
V(my_network)
E(my_network)

plot(my_network, edge.arrow.size=.5, vertex.color="red", vertex.size=10,
     vertex.frame.color="black", vertex.label.color="black", vertex.label.cex=0.5, 
     edge.colour="black", edge.width="0.5")
```

[image: Current network graph appearance]

Thank you.

Comment: You have `edge.width="0.5"` but do you mean `edge.width=0.5`?

Comment: For 1. you need to use `simplify()` with an attribute combiner that sums values.